# Magento custom translate.csv file not generating array pair

Tags: php, magento, csv

I know there are a lot of related questions, but I've searched and tried a lot and nothing so far.

I'm adding custom translations to my translate file. The path of the file is ok, Magento is vieweing it, and adding the new rows to the translation table. Problem is, the new rows are not coming in the format like the originakl translations:

**correct way>>>**

```
[First Day of Week] => Primeiro Dia da Semana
[Flush Cache Storage] => Armazenamento do Fluxo de Cache
```

and so on...

**then comes my translations.csv content**

```
["Regular Price","De"] => 
["Special Price:","Por"] =>
```

Using exactly the same pattern as the original csv files (double quotes and comma). Tried to edit on Excell and Wordpad, no difference. When I add the lines on a existing csv file it works... but i want to use my own one.

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of an existing file and edit that.